# Get token parameter inside of .ConfirmationURL to reset password on reset password template supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

i need get the token to reset password user in the reset password email template becuase i will send this token in firebase deep link but the parameter .ConfirmationURL has url with more information, i just need get the token, there is the posibility of get this parameter with a especific name inside the template as .ConfirmationURL? thanks

**Update**
i have configuration all parameter as shown in the documentation:

1. Additional redirect URLs

[image]

2. FLutter initialization

   await Supabase.initialize(
   url: supabaseUrl,
   anonKey: supabaseAnnonKey,
   authCallbackUrlHostname: 'login-callback',
   debug: true,
   localStorage: SecureLocalStorage(),
   );
3. if i send the reset email this send fine with a link as the picture, the content of link is this

https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.supabase.co/auth/v1/verify?token=kiaknuztglhtdcynoaog&type=recovery&redirect_to=https://localhost:3000

[image]

Now if i click in the link since the phone, it does not redirect me to the application, but the user is logged in the supabase panel automatically.

[image]

I dont understand what i do wrong and for this reason i try use firebase to deep links but the access_token parameter cannot be accessed. so i think that i need help in the last step

[image]

**Update 2**

Finally works, i use the parameter redirectTo inside of resetPasswordEmail and the deeplink connect with the app:

```
    response = await clientSupabase.auth.api.resetPasswordForEmail(
    datauser.email,
    options: AuthOptions(redirectTo: Credentials.myAuthRedirectUri),
  );
```

2. Aditional i use the next configuration in setting configuration authentication supabase:

[image]

3. In flutter code i use the next method in the login page, this method just is called when the user clik the link in the reset password mail:

   @override
   void onReceivedAuthDeeplink(Uri uri) {}

Comment: Hi there. Is there a particular reason why you want to receive the deep link via firebase dynamic links? Supabase has a flutter SDK that will take care of deeplinks for password refresh automatically for you. Would love to hear if this will solve your case.  https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter

Comment: Hi dshukertjr i update the post for more details, please could help me. I would be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems that you are redirecting to localhost:3000 upon sign up, but you actually want to redirect to the deeplink you have setup.

When you signup, you can provide a `options` with `redirectTo` set as the deeplink you have setup within Supabase's console to redirect the user to a certain page instead of the default site  URL.

```dart
Supabase.instance.client.auth
  .signUp('email', 'password', options: AuthOptions(redirectTo: 'io.supabase.flutterquickstart://login-callback/'));
```

Comment: Thx bro with this and other changes finally works